# Binomial Transform of a Particular Binomial Sum

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n + 1}{k}b_k.
$$
I am trying to write $b_n$ in terms of $a_k$.

Of course, if the binomial coefficient was $\binom{n}{k}$ instead of $\binom{n + 1}{k}$, then this is simple to do using the binomial transform,
$$
c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}d_k \iff d_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}c_k.
$$
But in my case I'm at a loss. I tried using Pascal's identity, thinking I might be able to use the formula for the binomial transform if I could get $a_n$ expressed in terms of $b_k$ in the right way. This got me to
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}b_k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}b_{k + 1},
$$
which is *almost* right, but not quite. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Define $a_k$ for $k\ne n$.

Comment: By "write $b_n$ in terms of $a_k$" I mean "write $b_n$ as a linear combination of $a_k$, where $k = 1, \dots, n$." Here the definition of $a_k$ for $k \ne n$ is analogous to the definition of $c_k$ for $k \ne n$.

Comment: How is $c_k$ defined?  Try to be explicit.

Comment: Do you know generating functions? How do you show the binomial transformation?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $\{c_i\}$ and $\{d_i\}$ are finite sequences related by the binomial transform. Defining one of these sequences defines the other. So, given $\{d_i\}$, $c_k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}d_i$ for all $k = 0, \dots, n$.

Comment: @Phicar Not in this context, no. It's not too hard to derive the binomial transform using elementary methods, but maybe the generating function approach is better here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seek is not quite a binomial transform.  Use the elementary ID
$$ \binom{n+1}{k} = \frac{n+1}{n+1-k} \binom{n}{k}.$$
Define $A_n=a_n/(n+1)$ and the sum you want to invert is
$$ A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{b_k}{n-k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{b_{n-k}}{k+1} $$
where in the last step the sum has been performed in opposite order. Now Riordan, 'Combinatorial Identities,' eq 3.4.(17) states the inversion
$$ A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{b_{n-k}}{k+1} \implies
 b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k A_{n-k} $$
where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers $B_0=1, \ B_1=-1/2, \  B_{2n+1} = 0.$

Example: $a_n=(2^n-1)(n+1),$ $A_n=2^{n}-1,$ then
$$ b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_k (2^{n-k} -1 ) = n .$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow-up question: Fix $n > 0$ and define the finite sequence $\{c_0, \dots, c_n\}$ by $c_j = b_j (n + 1) / (n - j + 1)$. Then $a_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}c_k$, which is (presumably) amenable to the binomial transform: $c_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}a_k$. But $c_n = (n+1)b_n$. So, $b_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}a_k$. This doesn't seem to work. What went wrong?

Comment: @mfox Hello.  The sequence $c_j$ must depend only on $j,$ that is, it must be independent of $n.$

Answer (score 2):

Given
$$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n + 1}{k}b_k. \tag{1} $$
Let the exponential generating functions (e.g.f.) for $\,a_n\,$ and $\,b_n\,$ be
$$ A(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n/n! \quad \text{ and }
  \quad B(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n/n!. \tag{2} $$
Multiply both sides of equation $(1)$ by $\,\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\,$
and sum over $\,n\ge0\,$ to get
$$ \int_0^x A(t)\,dt = (e^x-1) B(x). \tag{3} $$
Thus
$$ B(x) = \frac{x}{e^x-1} \left(\frac1x \int_0^x A(t)\,dt\right) \tag{4} $$
where $\,\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}\,$ is the e.g.f. of the Bernoulli numbers.
The 2nd factor is the e.g.f. of $\,\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}.\,$ Thus,
$$ b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_{n-k} \frac{a_k}{k+1}. \tag{5} $$

---

Note: For the binomial transform, $\,A(x) = e^x B(x)\,$ is equivalent
to $\, B(x) = e^{-x}A(x).\,$